# Haskell convert list of strings to string with divider "|"

Tags: haskell

How can I convert a list to string with divider "|", using foldl'?

```
ltos :: String -> [String] -> String
ltos  []    = ""
ltos  (m:n) = foldl' f acc xs
   where
     f a b          = 
     acc            = 
     xs             =
```

for example,

```
ltos ["a", "b", "c"]
```

would output

```
"a|b|c"
```

Comment: `Data.List.intercalate "|"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a cute combination of pattern matching and HOF.

```
ltos :: [String] -> String
ltos []    = ""
ltos (m:n) = foldl' (\a b -> a ++ "|" ++ b) m n
```

You use the first element of the list as the starting string, then fold over the remaining elements (adding `|` between each of them).

(I'm assuming that you mistyped the signature to `ltos`).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way:

```
foldl' (\acc x -> if (null acc) then acc ++ x else acc ++ "|" ++ x) [] ["a", "b", "c"]
```

The first time accumulator is empty, so just append the first string from the list. Thereafter, append the separator before the variable. If you run `scanl`, you can see the string being built as follows:

```
["","a","a|b","a|b|c"]
```